# What link should i use for home- & owncloud-data?

Tags: mount, symlink, hard-link, ln, bind-mount

the plan is to built a debian-based sever with [owncloud](https://owncloud.org/) for syncing addressbooks, calendars, files etc. and also access large video-files in the LAN via webdav from some [kodi](https://kodi.tv/)-clients (maybe also [use MySQL to store the kodi-settings](http://kodi.wiki/view/MySQL)).
from time to time the same machine will be used via GUI (VNC and/or direct screen) for resource-hungry tasks like ripping, video-encoding etc., everything else will be done with mobile devices and lightweight SBCs.

**my question is how can i link the home-folder** (/home/"os_user"/) **and the owncloud data-files** (/var/www/owncloud/data/"oc_user"/files/)**?** - i don't want to normally "upload"/sync the files since it is the same machine and will use twice the space!
and i'm also afraid of messing up the user-rights...!

---

my answers/research/guesses so far:

- **hardlinks** are unusable because i have to create every folder twice, link every file one by one (via command-line) and also have to delete every file twice.
- **softlinks** work, but i'm not sure if it is the best solution (i still have problems with the user-rights)... and what should be the master?
- is **`mount --bind`** (executed via `/etc/fstab`) the better way? ...what should be the master? and what's with the user-rights?!?
- or is there a completely different solution i never thought about...?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply symlink `/home/os_user` to `/var/www/owncloud/data/oc_user/files/home` and be done with it. By default you will have a read-only access to those files (if at all), pepending on how permissions on your system are configured. You will have to tweak the permissions to obtain full access.

What I would recommend intead is to create a special folder with relaxed permissions (e.g. `/home/os_user/share` and symlink it to Owncloud tree. That would keep important files (like `~/.Xauthority`) safe even if your OwnCloud account is compromised.

Also note that if you modify/remove files via the OS, OwnCloud will not be able to track versions and undelete them (which is kind of obvious if you think about it).

Comment: thank you for your answer! -- i unfortunately had to stop this project because lack of time but in a few months i will go further and confirm your answer if it works/helped...!

Comment: Hint: on my machine Owncloud runs as `www-data` user, so you'll have to give that user RX permissions to `/home/os_user` and RWX permissions to `/home/os_user/share`. Putting `os_user` and `www-data` in the same group might make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am running a [nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com) cloud in a similar setup (and it's basically owncloud as of 2018).  My research led me to believe that there was really no way around the duplicate-file problem!  If I wanted nextcloud to pay attention to any edits I made in my home directory, I have to have it synced with the nextcloud repository.  So, basically, :(

If you don't care about ever editing files - e.g., movies, large videos, whatever - you could "upload" them to the server (making 2 copies) and then delete the local copy (back to one), and then just have a soft link to the repository for that directory.

It's not ideal, I know, but I wasn't able to find a way around it.  Maybe you will have more luck and/or someone will write a solution at some point!

I do quite like having my own person cloud, though, so that's good at least!